# How to find merge_base of 2 git-svn clones (original + fork) in git?

Tags: git

I have two git-svn clones, one of the "original" and the other of the "fork". While they have distinct histories, they have the same diffs up to a certain point.

I'm trying to stitch this back to one git-repo and I'm trying to find the "merge-base" based on change diffs, so I can rebase the changes in the fork onto "original" that specific point, preserving the "correct" history.

Comment: Was the forked repo done with `svn cp`? e.g. `svn cp repo/project-original repo/project-forked`?

Answer (score -1):

What about a `git merge`?

```
cd project-original
git remote add project-forked path/to/git-repo
git fetch project-forked
git merge project-forked
git commit
```

I feel like entire forks of projects are normally ment to be merged together, not rebased together. Would this option work for you?

(also, I have no real experience with git-svn. So don't take my suggestions as gospel truth :) )

Comment: The question is about restoring the original fork point and re-attaching at that point.